# Scripting exercise

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to complete a home work scripting assignment for which I have been essentially thought nothing about and need to find/research a fix for a script. The script i need to run looks at a  three column (name, ID, department) file (that I was give) and is supposed supposed to create new groups and users and assign users to the correct group. Each group can only be created once. My issue is using the FOR /f command with token.

File 1

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /p userfFile="what is the file that contains new hires: "

REM Loop through the lines of the file
REM and copy the the department names to a new file
FOR /f "tokens=3 skip=4" %%b IN (%userfFile%) DO ECHO %%b >> Department.txt

REM sort the file back into itself
sort Department.txt /0 Department.txt

REM a variable to keep track of the groups that have neen created 
SET LastGroupCreated=None

FOR /f %%a IN (Department.txt) DO CALL CUG

FOR /f "tokens=2,3 skip=4" %%A IN (%userfFile%) DO CALL

REM Clean Up
DEL Department.txt
SET userfFile=
```

File 2 "CUG"

```
REM Have we already processed this name (%1) ?
IF "%LastGroupCreated%"=="%1" GOTO :EOF

REM Not Processed, so create and update the variable
NET LOCALGROUP /ADD %1
SET LastGroupCreated=%1
```

I believe file CUG is good but file one keeps giving me errors. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this. I have tried everything that i can think of and am stuck

Cheers

James

Answer (score 0):

few mistakes:

`FOR /f %%a IN (Department.txt) DO CALL CUG`

1. in this for you call `CUG` without parameters, but you do use `%1`.
   you should make `CUG` a subroutine instead of a different file and pass a parameter to `CUG`.
2. in `CUG` file you reuse `%LastGroupCreated%` you need to `SETLOCAL NABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in the beginning of you file.
3. `FOR /f "tokens=2,3 skip=4" %%A IN (%userfFile%) DO CALL` - call what?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
...
FOR /f %%a IN (Department.txt) DO CALL :CUG %%a
...
goto :eof

:CUG
REM Have we already processed this name (%1) ?
IF "!LastGroupCreated!"=="%1" GOTO :EOF

REM Not Processed, so create and update the variable
NET LOCALGROUP /ADD %1
SET LastGroupCreated=%1
goto :eof
```